# How to find equilibrium points of this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields

I'm trying to find the equilibrium points for the vector field of the following differential equation:
$$\frac{d^2\Psi}{dt^2}= \frac{g}{\xi\ell}\sin{\xi\Psi}-\frac{V^2}{\xi \ell R}\frac{\cos{\xi \Psi}}{\cos{\Psi}}\mathrm{sgn}\Psi,$$ for $\ 0≤\xi≤1.$

I tried doing this:

At equilibrium points, conditions are: $\frac{d^2\Psi}{dt^2}=\frac{d\Psi}{dt}=0;\ \Psi=\Psi_{eq}$. Thus, the differential equation reduces to this:
$$0=\sin{\xi\Psi_{eq}}-\frac{V^2}{g R}\frac{\cos{\xi \Psi_{eq}}}{\cos{\Psi_{eq}}}\mathrm{sgn}\Psi_{eq},$$ where $0≤\frac{V^2}{g R}≤2\ \mathrm{or}\ 3.$

This most likely isn't solvable analitically, so I thought about doing an average or approximating. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, we can eliminate $\operatorname{sgn}(\Psi)$ by by noting that if $\Psi$ is a solution, so is $-\Psi$. We are studying the transcendental equation

$$\tag{1}
\sin(\xi \Psi)=\beta\frac{\cos(\xi\Psi)}{\cos(\Psi)}
$$

I've grouped the other constants into $\beta$. An analytical solution is not likely, but we can estimate the solutions for different extreme values of $\xi$.

As $\xi\to 0$, $\Phi \propto1/\xi\to\infty$, which suggests defining $f=\xi \Psi$ so that $f$ is of order unity. Then (1) becomes

$$\tag{2}
\tan(f)\cos(f/\xi)=\beta
$$

The solutions of (2) are not-quite $2\pi$ periodic.  I start by plotting the LHS and RHS of (2) as functions of $f$.

[image]

As $\xi\to0$, the solutions are contained in the interval

$$
\tan^{-1}(\beta)<f<\pi-\tan^{-1}(\beta)
$$

Every oscillation of $\cos(f/\xi)$ yields two solutions, and the interval length is $\pi-2\tan^{-1}(\beta)$, so there are approximately $N=\left(1-\frac{2}{\pi}\tan^{-1}(\beta)\right)/\xi$ solutions for every interval of length $\pi$ in $f$. The first root is approximately in the interval

$$
\tan^{-1}(\beta)\leq f\leq \tan^{-1}(\beta) +2\pi \xi
$$

As $\xi \to 1$ there are always solutions near $\Psi=\pi(n+1/2)$, as well as several other solutions that may exist depending on the size of $\beta$. Multiply (1) by $\cos(\Phi)$, and let and $\xi=1-\varepsilon$ to get

$$\tag{3}
\sin((1-\varepsilon)\Psi)\cos(\Psi)=\beta \cos((1-\varepsilon)\Psi)
$$

We can develop a perturbation series to the roots: let $\Psi=\sum\limits_n \varepsilon^n x_n$. Substitute into (3) and match coefficients at each order of $\varepsilon$. At $\varepsilon^0$ I find

$$
\cos(x_0)\left[\beta-\sin(x_0) \right]=0\\
\therefore \cos(x_0)=0 \qquad \text{or} \qquad \sin(x_0)=\beta
$$

The $\cos(x_0)=0$ possibility furnishes all the roots near $\pi(n+1/2)$, and the $\sin(x_0)=\beta$ finds the others (the ones that exist conditionally on $\beta$). At $\varepsilon^1$ I find

$$
x_1=x_0 \frac{\cos^2(x_0)+\beta\sin(x_0)}{\cos^2(x_0)+(\beta-\sin(x_0))\sin(x_0)}
$$

It is straightforward but tedious to continue to higher orders. Note that the approximation is not *uniform* in $\beta$. Here is a plot of the LHS and RHS of (3). The vertical red lines are first three approximate roots at $\Psi= x_0+\varepsilon x_1$.

[image]

Comment: Very very nice. It is not unusual to give $\xi$ values very small that tend to 0, so don't worry. As for the rest, looks good to me, though I'm new to some things you mentioned like perturbation series and some others.

Comment: One question: how did you get $x_{1}$?

Comment: @JoanSGF Great, no problem! To find $x_1$ (or for that matter $x_0$ or any of the $x_n$), take a Taylor series of equation (3) in $\varepsilon$ around the point $\varepsilon=0$. Then equate coefficients of $\varepsilon$ on LHS and RHS for each power of $\varepsilon$

Comment: But take the Taylor series of the RHS and LHS equations or only all trigonometric functions? I suppose the first...

Comment: From (3) let us write LHS -RHS as $T(\varepsilon)=\sin\left[(1-\varepsilon)\Psi(\varepsilon)\right]\cos\left[\Psi(\varepsilon)\right]-\beta \cos\left[(1-\varepsilon)\Psi(\varepsilon)\right]=0$, with $\Psi(\varepsilon)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \varepsilon^n x_n$. Then Taylor expand $T(\varepsilon)$ in $\varepsilon$. This means lots chain rule application since $\Psi=\Psi(\varepsilon)$

Comment: Oh I see now. Thanks. I'll try to do at least til' $\epsilon^2$

Comment: I may be mistaken but as for $x_1$ I get $x_1=x_0 \frac{\cos^2(x_0)+\beta\sin(x_0)}{\cos^2(x_0)+(\beta-\sin(x_0))\sin(x_0)}$ with a $\sin(x_0)$ instead of a 1

Comment: Yes, that was a typo on my part- it's corrected now

Comment: Thank you so much. I found $x_2$ too. Do you know whether I could write a code to solve for higher orders in Python?

Comment: No problem! I don't know much about coding or Python so I can't really say. If you wanted to generate terms in the series I'd suggest a symbolic calculator like Maple or Mathematica

Comment: Ok, I saw one code on the internet to do it in Mathematica. Thanks anyways.